# Blender 3.1.2 Eevee Transparency Problem

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

I'm having an issue regarding eevee's transparency as in here:

[image]

I have already enabled refraction:

[image]

and Screen Space Refraction in the Material tab:

[image]

This 3d Model was downloaded from poliigon it looks fine in cycles render as shown below:

[image]

You can clearly see the blades inside the blender.
its not present in eevee render though.

Here's a comparison between the two renders:

[image]

this is the transmission material provided with the 3d model:

[image]

The problem is I have to render this scene in eevee for a quick animation, so cycles is not a good choice for me,
I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, if you can call it that.

I noticed that it is transparent to everything except itself. I tried putting the glass next to the espresso machine, and voila: it's transparent!

So I took the blade out of the Blender model and created a new material for it (*This is important because the same material or a duplicate material won't work*) and added the texture specified for the 3D model and it works!

[image]
[image]

If anyone has this problem, here is a workaround for it:

[image]